# mysql update query failing

Tags: php, mysql

My query code is:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE books SET read = 'y' WHERE id = 2") or die(mysql_error());
```

and the error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read = 'y' WHERE id = 2' at line 1
```

Comment: I hope your `read` field is an ENUM and not a VARCHAR. If it's a VARCHAR change it to `ENUM('y', 'n')` to make it nore efficient.

Comment: Additionally you can probably get rid of the `$query = ` part unless you need the return value (to check the number of affected rows or something similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Enclose it in backticks:

```
UPDATE books SET `read` = 'y' WHERE id = '2'
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html for a list of reserved keywords.

Comment: @Gary: Please mark it as the solution, then. :)